# No request data ($this->request->data is empty array) when post_max_size exceeded

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a form with a file upload element on it (set to allow multiple file selection - `echo $this->Form->file('filename.', array('multiple' => 'multiple'));`), and when the size of files selected by the user exceeds the PHP value of post_max_size I get no error, but $this->request->data is an empty array.

Is this the expected behaviour, it doesn't seem right to me?

Comment: That is indeed the expected behavior, PHP drops all POST data in that case. **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476139/php-post-files-empty-when-upload-larger-than-post-max-size**