# form does not send data with enctype=multipart/formdata

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple PHP form with 2 upload inputs on localhost. When i set the enctype of the form to `multipart/form-data`, it does not send any information. i printed the `$_FILES` and the `$_POST` and both were `Array()` and empty. 
this is my php code inside `insert_tour.php` file:

```
$path = "upload/";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {

    $image_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];

    $image_path = $path . basename($_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $image_path)) {
        array_push($images, $image_path);

    } else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the images, please try again!";
    }
}


$video_path = $path . basename($_FILES['tour_video']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tour_video']['tmp_name'], $video_path)) {

} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the video, please try again!";
}
// Process the post data and files and send to db here ...
```

And this is my form code:

```
<form action="tour_insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- other inputs for form --> 
    <input name="tour_video" type="file">
    <input name="images[]" type="file" multiple="multiple">
    <input name="add_tour" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The problem is it does not send any information in `$_POST` or `$_FILES`. 
This is what printing the `$_SERVER` gives me:

```
Array ( [UNIQUE_ID] => WmCTwKwSjVEAABJMH-QAAAA- [HTTP_HOST] => localhost [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive [CONTENT_LENGTH] => 14532844 [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0 [HTTP_ORIGIN] => http://localhost [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1 [CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarydQZ9i0QtJC8p0A5e [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36 [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8 [HTTP_REFERER] => http://localhost/dalahu/add_tour.php [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, br [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7 [HTTP_COOKIE] => PHPSESSID=s44btr20s2to36kn7tsk4rk717 [PATH] => C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Users\Amirition\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\Amirition\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;D:\Python\ajax_lastsecond\chromedriver.exe;C:\Users\Amirition\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Bandizip\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin [SystemRoot] => C:\Windows [COMSPEC] => C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe [PATHEXT] => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC [WINDIR] => C:\Windows [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.27 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.2e mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 PHP/7.0.0 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.16.3 [SERVER_NAME] => localhost [SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1 [SERVER_PORT] => 80 [REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1 [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => D:/MAMP/htdocs [SERVER_ADMIN] => testemail@test.com [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => D:/MAMP/htdocs/dalahu/tour_insert.php [REMOTE_PORT] => 3105 [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1 [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1 [REQUEST_METHOD] => POST [QUERY_STRING] => [REQUEST_URI] => /dalahu/tour_insert.php [SCRIPT_NAME] => /dalahu/tour_insert.php [PHP_SELF] => /dalahu/tour_insert.php [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1516278720.141 [REQUEST_TIME] => 1516278720 )
```

Comment: Are you closing the form tag after the inputs?

Comment: The next debugging step would be printing out `$_SERVER` and check HTTP_ request details for what you expect. Also peeking with your browsers devtools at the same would be advisable. -- Your issue isn't reproducible *only* with the code shown here.

Comment: @esteban-garcia Yes i close it, i forgot to do it here because my code was long.

Comment: @simon the submit button is the add_tour input.

Comment: @mario Just added the `$_SERVER` result to the question. My code was working an hour ago, but for no reason it just stopped working.

Comment: That's not a very readable dump. Notably `[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 14532844` is [a bit much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6190713/how-to-detect-if-a-user-uploaded-a-file-larger-than-post-max-size) though. And since you're using Windows, a reboot is always the first step when things don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem solved by increasing `post_max_size` in `php.ini` file. The default value is 8MB, you can increase this value.